# remove margin between swiper elements

Tags: html, css, margin, swiper.js

I'm using this slider from swiperjs.com:

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/vrs48z?file=%2Findex.html%3A9%2C45

and I was wondering if there was a way to remove the margin space between the slides.

I was able to edit them from the DevTool by changing the `margin-right:50px;` into `34px`
in the `<div class="swiper-slide">` style

Comment: Can't you just change `spaceBetween` to 0 in the javascript code that you have in your index file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the spaceBetween parameter describer in `Swiper API documentation`

```
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  speed: 400,
  spaceBetween: 100,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by giving `margin: 0` to your swiper element.

Answer (score -1):

just add `margin-right:0px !important` to your `swiper-slide` class

```
.swiper-slide {
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 18px;
   background: #fff;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   margin-right: 0px !important; // Add this line
}
```

happy coding :)